# Expiration date is not woking in Parse push notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push

I'm writing an app that uses push notifications widely, so push notifications reliability is very important for app.

I send push notification through parse cloud code function

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPush", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('userObjectId', request.params.toUser);
query.exists("deviceToken");

Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
        "alert": request.params.alert,
        "sound": "default",
        "type": request.params.type,
        "status": request.params.status,
        "fromUserId": request.params.fromUserId,
        "fromUserName": request.params.fromUserName,
        "messageId": request.params.messageId
    }
    }, { success: function() { 
        response.success("success");
    }, error: function(err) { 
        response.error("error");
    }
    }); 
});
```

This function delivers pushes great if my iPhone is online. But if i turn off internet on my iPhone for 30 seconds and send push, this push is not delivered when i turn internet on. So i tried to set expiration date in my parse cloud code function to improve reliability of delivering pushes when device isn't online.

```
// Expiration_interval added
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPush", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.equalTo('userObjectId', request.params.toUser);
  query.exists("deviceToken");

  Parse.Push.send({
    expiration_interval: 24 * 60 * 60,
    where: query,
    data: {
        "alert": request.params.alert,
        "sound": "default",
        "type": request.params.type,
        "status": request.params.status,
        "fromUserId": request.params.fromUserId,
        "fromUserName": request.params.fromUserName,
        "messageId": request.params.messageId
    }
    }, { success: function() { 
        response.success("success");
    }, error: function(err) { 
        response.error("error");
    }
}); 
});
```

But it is still not working even if i turn off internet for just a 30 secs.

Thanks for any helps/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is an artifact related to the Apple Quality of Service guidelines for the PUSH system.

In practice, it means that sometimes pushes will be missed. If they are crucial to your design, I suggest creating a database table of pushes that will deliver messages or data and have the app check on each load for new messages.

In practice, this means the push will not always get the attention of your users, but at least all the data will be delivered.

You can learn more at the parse.com help thread here: https://www.parse.com/questions/sending-push-notifications-quickly-causes-some-notifications-to-be-missed

As well as the Apple documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW4